# TensorFlow shuffle sub-tensor in place

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `X` of shape `(N,...)` and a boolean index mask `mask` of shape `N`. I want to shuffle the subarray of `X` given by `mask` along the first axis.

How can this be done non-eagerly and, if possible, in place?

Note: I do not need gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def shuffle_mask(x, mask, seed=None):
    n = tf.size(mask)
    # Get masked indices
    idx_masked = tf.cast(tf.where(mask), n.dtype)
    # Shuffle masked indices
    idx_masked_shuffled = tf.random.shuffle(tf.squeeze(idx_masked, 1), seed=seed)
    # Scatter shuffled indices into place
    idx_masked_shuffled_scat = tf.scatter_nd(idx_masked, idx_masked_shuffled, [n])
    # Combine shuffled and non-shuffled indices
    idx_shuffled = tf.where(mask, idx_masked_shuffled_scat, tf.range(n))
    # Gather using resulting indices
    return tf.gather(x, idx_shuffled)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    x = tf.constant([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]])
    mask = tf.constant([True, False, True, True, False])
    y = shuffle_mask(x, mask)
    print(sess.run(y))
    # [[6 7]
    #  [2 3]
    #  [0 1]
    #  [4 5]
    #  [8 9]]
```

You cannot do the operation "in place", as there are no in-place operations at all in TensorFlow. Tensors are constant, so you will always be replacing one tensor with another.